# php split array string into data

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode

Below script is shown search string in a text file, my text file has contents like:

> 60, 1, 1, 188, pdgje5566
>
> 60, 1, 1, 188, pdgje5565

```
if(!empty($extTxId)){
$searchfor = $extTxId;

$matches = array();

$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($buffer, $searchfor) !== FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

print_r($matches);
```

it output as

> Array ( [0] => 60, 1, 1, 188, ppje5566 )

however i want to explode the data which is separate by comma(,) and store into variable, is that anyway to do it?

thanks.

Comment: Ummm, you mean `$tokens = explode(",", $str);` ? The function is literally called explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have spaces between each comma, you can trim each element.

```
// Iterate through each item int the array (you can do $matches[0] if you just want the first)
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
     $output_array = array_map('trim',explode(',',$match));

     print_r($output_array);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 60
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 188
    [4] => pdgje5565
)
```

Example: http://codepad.org/aSyVX5Bj

Comment: Not really, if one doesn't happen to have a space, you're screwed.

Comment: Agreed. `fgetcsv()` will account for this though. Most of these answers simply rebuild its functionality.

Comment: I realize, but he wasn't using `fgetcsv()`, which is why I answered in this manner

Comment: heh, agreed, much better in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

> i want to explode the data which is separate by comma(,)

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

If this is a CSV file (or some other *delimited* file), I suggest looking at [`fgetcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). It is effectively `fgets()` and `explode()`, which seems to be what you need.

Comment: i had try explode(",",$matches)  but no luck, any sample?

Comment: Based on your array, you can't do it on `$matches` as that is the entire array. You need to do it on the elements, e.g. `$matches[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
foreach(Array[0] as $element)
{
     echo $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact structure of the input you're getting, you could do something like:

```
$string = '60, 1, 1, 188, pdgje5565';
// Using trim just to be sure
list($varA, $varB, $varC, $varD, $varE) = explode(', ', trim($string));
```

This way you would get the results as follows:

```
$varA = 60;
$varB = 1;
$varC = 1;
$varD = 188;
$varE = 'pdgje5565';
```

The main advantage here is you would get decent variables instead of array with abstract indexes, but it is only good if you're sure about you're structure being constant.